# Jquery Fadeout won't work upon clicking of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show a `<div>` that displays "Saved!" every time the user clicks the save button.

I have here some jQuery code but it works only once.  The second time I click the button the div won't show up.

```
$("#loading").html("Saved!").fadeOut(4000);
```

Comment: "it works only once, the second time I click the button the div won't show up", because you faded it out the first time, you can't fade an already faded div :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the div is still "faded out"

try this...

```
$("#loading").html("Saved!").fadeOut(4000, function(){
    $("#loading").empty();
    $("#loading").show();
});
```

It empties the `#loading` div and then re-displays it and readies it for the next click.

Comment: Make sure to mark it as correct.  Depending on which solution you used.

Comment: yeah. it says here i can accept the answer after a couple of minutes. it works just fine. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly because it is hidden. Try:

```
$("#loading").html("Saved!").show().fadeOut(4000);
```

Or

```
$("#loading").html("Saved!").fadeIn(200).fadeOut(4000);
```

Comment: thanks. thought it is visible and it works just fine the first time I click the button. The second click, it won't work.

Comment: @Zend - Why would it be visible? The first click hides it, and you never show it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a click event to a a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#element').click(function() {
            $('#para').html("Saved!").fadeOut(4000);
        });
    });
```